# When the object-created event is triggered in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Need to work with large files uploads to a bucket (S3), using Lambda function triggered with the `object-created` event to start processing it ***after is completed***

Upload call from a client in java:

`transferUtility.upload("folder", file.getName(), file);`

(a `TransferObserver` type)

But looking into the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html can't find explicitly when the event is trigger.

The past tense suggest is after all is up, but does anyone knows it for sure or know where to find those details.

---

Observing more in detail logs inserted from `console.log()` in CloudWatch, there are two entries one with:

`{
   "key": "testing-dev/test150.mp4",
   "size": 0,
   "eTag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
   "sequencer": "005B16EEECE6C6C90D"
}`
and the other with:

`{
   "key": "testing-dev/test150.mp4",
   "size": 432351,
   "eTag": "05d53b99cba51a1f5c79532fb4effe40",
   "sequencer": "005B16EEECEF2AA80F"
}`

for the `object` element in the event variable:
`event.Records[0].s3.object`

Note the `"size": 0` in the first entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is fired immediately after the upload is complete.

Uploads to S3 are atomic -- a failed or interrupted upload does not actually create an object at all -- so, by definition, the event cannot fire until the operation is complete, because no object has been created until that point.

Answer (score 1):

It will be triggered at the end of the upload.

If you are using a Multipart upload, it will happen after the *complete multipart upload* operation has finished.