# Listen to aws s3 bucket when upload file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem that I need to know if anyone has an idea how to solve it..
I need to create something that listens to the s3 bucket when a file is uploaded there and actually take the file they uploaded and manipulate it in my website with all kinds of processes that I already have

So basically, is there something like this that lets me listen to uploads that have been made in s3 and then manipulate it?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the object-created event is triggered in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691109/when-the-object-created-event-is-triggered-in-aws)

Comment: I think it can help.  If I understand correctly, I will put a trigger as you wrote and then I will get details about the uploaded files and to take the file I will use get object? @fedonev

Comment: Search the interwebs or SO for "S3 Event Notifications".

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this.
First enable `S3 Notification` that will be triggered on `s3 PutObject`, and trigger any of these -

- `Lambda` - gets the object and processes (not for large files, lambda can run for 15 mint)
- put new object notifications in a `SQS queue`. Then launch `ec2 instances` to process the files. You can use `autoscaling` and `cloudwatch alarm` with it. Get some ideas [from here](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/AWS-AutoScale-MediaProcessor).
  Or some more.

My suggestion would be this -

**s3 notification -> Trigger Lambda -> get object key and run ec2 instance -> ec2 does the hard work**

> No ideas are perfect, it highly depends on your system. Look for better solution that meets your need.

Best wishes.